# How to save an object whose name is in a variable?

Tags: r

This is calling for some "tricky R", but this time it's beyond my fantasy :-) I need to `save()` an object whose name is in the variable `var`. I tried:

```
save(get(var), file = ofn)
# Error in save(get(var), file = ofn) : object ‘get(var)’ not found

save(eval(parse(text = var)), file = ofn)
# Error in save(eval(parse(text = var)), file = ofn) : 
#  object ‘eval(parse(text = var))’ not found
```

both of which fail, unfortunatelly. How would you solve this?

Comment: I usually do, but in this case I thought it's so simple it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `list` argument.  This saves `x` in the file x.RData.  (The `list` argument can specify a vector of names if you need to save more than one at a time.)

```
x <- 3
name.of.x <- "x"
save(list = name.of.x, file = "x.RData")

# loading x.RData to check that it worked
rm(x)
load("x.RData")
x
## [1] 3
```

### Note

Regarding the first attempt in the question which attempts to use `get` we need to specify the name rather than its value so that attempt could use `do.call` converting the character name to a `name` class object.

```
do.call("save", list(as.name(name.of.x), file = "x.RData"))
```

Regarding the second attempt in the question which uses `eval`, to do that write out the `save`, substitute in its name as a `name` class object and then evaluate it.

```
eval(substitute(save(Name, file = "x.RData"), list(Name = as.name(name.of.x))))
```

Comment: wow, amazing! I was looking at `?save` but I totally missed this argument! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one object, you can use `saveRDS`:

```
a<-1:4
var<-"a"
saveRDS(get(var),file="test.R")
readRDS(file="test.R")
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: thanks, but this creates some different format than `.Rdata`. I prefer to stay with `.Rdata`.